# nextjs mounted component not fetching data

Tags: next.js

I am using nextJs and have 1 page - `index.js` and a component that I am importing to `index.js` called `Products`. Products contains a request to a graphql endpoint that I am fetching data from.

I get the error f`Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` on `products.map` as I presume it's not doing the fetch request.

How can I perform the request when the `Products` component is mounted in `index.js`?

(the code in `Products` works if I paste into the `index.js` file directly)

**index.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Products from '../components/Products'

const Layout = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Products />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

**products.js**

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(
    "https://api-eu-central-1.graphcms.com/v2/ckbmb39xb04eo01wh7yc80q8m/master"
  );

  const { products } = await graphcms.request(
    `
      { 
        products {
          slug
          name
        }
      }
    `
  );

  return {
    props: {
      products
    }
  };
}

export default ({ products }) => 
  products.map(({ slug, name }) => (
    <Link key={slug} href={`/products/${slug}`}>
      <a>{name}</a>
    </Link>
  ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getStaticPath](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) can only be called from page `i.e index.js` so you need to move the `export getStaticProps` to index.js and pass products as a prop to your `products.js` component.

Or if you want to fetch data on client you can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook in your product component